# Símbolos em tempo de compilação

Tags: c, compilação

Ao compilar apenas com `-c` e ao visualizar os símbolos com `$nm ficheiro.o`, o que significa o símbolo `C` e qual a secção que lhe é atribuída?

Já li que significa que o símbolo é comum e que é data não iniciada, mas em que casos é que este símbolo é atribuído e qual a diferença para o símbolo `B/b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vejamos...

De forma sucinta, simplista e considerando o **Linux**, o **C**, o **GCC**, **Assembly** e as fases de compilação:

- Dados globais e estáticos não inicializados e inicializados com 0 são colocados na seção `.BSS`;
- Dados inicializadas com valores não-zero são alocadas a seção `.DATA` ou `.RODATA` no caso de constantes;
- Ao compilar em objeto (usando `-c` no GCC), os dados não inicializados vão para a seção `COMMON` - que existe no GCC por *retrocompatibilidade*. Quando ligados (*linking*) para formar o executável, são jogados na seção `.BSS` preenchidos com zero conforme necessário;

Provavelmente outros compiladores e SOs comportam-se de forma similar mas com algumas diferenças de comportamento. A exemplo, preencher completamente de zeros um dado não inicializado ou mesmo fazê-lo em tempo de execução conforme necessário.

### Respondendo

Desta forma, dado a base acima, temos o seguinte:

- O símbolo `b` é atribuído a dados locais não inicializados, preenchidos de zero pelo desenvolvedor ou inicializador do programa. São colocados em `.BSS`;
- O símbolo `B` é atribuído a dados globais não inicializadas, preenchidos de zero pelo desenvolvedor ou inicializador do programa. São colocados em `.BSS`;
- O símbolo `C` é atribuído a dados não inicializados quando se pula a fase de 'ligação' (linking). São colocados em `COMMON` pois podem conter outras referências iguais;