# Onde as Strings literais ficam armazenadas?

Tags: c

Considere o seguinte código em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Onde a String "Hello, world!\n" fica armazenada na memória? Fica armazenada junto ao binário do programa?

Detalhe: Uso o MinGW-GCC na versão estável mais atualizada possível.

Comment: Não tem uma resposta única, pois depende de alguns fatores, mas tem um 'common ground' conceitual que dá para explorar. Pra adiantar, em boa parte dos formatos de executável tem um .rodata ou .text para armazenar essas coisas, é algo que vai 'anexado' no executável - não é exatamente no meio do executável (mas em alguns cenários pode ser) mas faz parte do pacote. Espero que saia uma resposta boa disso aqui, é informação que voltou a ter muita relevância em embedded/IoT, onde voltamos a trabalhar com restrições de espaço e outros recursos.

Comment: Alguns links que podem ter parte da resposta ou da problemática: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/340098/70 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266634/70 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291997/70 - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/70

Comment: Eu vou tentar usar o xxd para procurar a String dentro do binário. Eu queria que fosse tão claro como é em Rust. Mas valeu pelas respostas...

Comment: Ainda não é resposta, é só uma prévia que pus para adiantar o assunto enquanto não sai resposta. provavelmente alguém com um tempinho extra vai elaborar alguma coisa legal. Enquanto isso, estude os formatos ELF e PE, são um ponto de partida.

Comment: Já não tem bastante para considerar duplicata? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446248/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301798/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/475268/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344024/101

Comment: Aqui ele diz que as Strings são armazenadas na memória estática: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446248/de-onde-vem-o-espa%c3%a7o-na-mem%c3%b3ria-necess%c3%a1rio-para-cada-elemento-em-um-array-de-str

Comment: @hslucasfernandes lá tem uma parte, mas acredito que insuficiente para a pergunta. No 1º comentário tem pontos que não foram cobertos (ex. detalhar onde fica essa parte estática - até tem partes em respostas diversas, mas se for pra fazer um estudo gigantesco, teria outras centenas de postagens que teriamos que fechar como duplicata). Dei uma pesquisada prévia, justamente não fechei como duplicata por notar que até o momento não encontrei algumas coisas relevantes concentradas em poucos lugares. Lembrando que respostas aqui não são só para caso individual, e sim para público amplo.

Answer (score 1):

## Resposta curta

Sim, fica armazenado junto ao binário do programa, em uma seção chamada `.rodata` (*read-only data*, ou "memória apenas de leitura").

Quando o programa é executado, o ponteiro para o trecho exato de `.rodata` que contém a string é carregado em um registrador e em seguida a função do sistema operacional que imprime no terminal é chamada.

## Resposta longa

*Eu não tenho o compilador MinGW-GCC aqui, então usei o GCC 11.4.0 rodando no Ubuntu do WSL2 para elaborar esta resposta.*

Eu copiei seu código em um arquivo C aqui e o compilei com o comando `gcc dúvida_memória.c`, que resultou em um arquivo `a.out`, que ao ser executado imprime `"Hello, world!"` no terminal, como esperado.

A partir disso, usei o comando [objdump](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) para listar o conteúdo do arquivo a.out:

```
objdump -Ss a.out
```

O conteúdo da saída tem quase 300 linhas, então vou reproduzir abaixo apenas os trechos de interesse (o colorido não é intencional):

```
…
Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 48656c6c 6f2c2077 6f726c64  ....Hello, world
 2010 2100
…
Disassembly of section .plt.sec:

0000000000001050 <puts@plt>:
    1050:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1054:       f2 ff 25 75 2f 00 00    bnd jmp *0x2f75(%rip)        # 3fd0 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    105b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

Disassembly of section .text:
…
0000000000001149 <main>:
    1149:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    114d:       55                      push   %rbp
    114e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1151:       48 8d 05 ac 0e 00 00    lea    0xeac(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1158:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
    115b:       e8 f0 fe ff ff          call   1050 <puts@plt>
    1160:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1165:       5d                      pop    %rbp
    1166:       c3                      ret
…
```

Imediatamente podemos ver o texto "Hello, world" na seção `.rodata`. Essa é uma seção que o GCC usa para armazenar dados apenas de leitura e que não podem ser modificados durante a execução do programa.

Já ao olharmos o código assembly da função `main`, quero chamar a atenção para as seguintes linhas.

```
    1151:       lea    0xeac(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1158:       mov    %rax,%rdi
    115b:       call   1050 <puts@plt>
```

O comando `lea 0xeac(%rip),%rax` carrega no registrador `rax` uma posição de memória `0xeac` bytes depois do contador de programa.

Teríamos que fazer contas para saber qual posição de memória é essa, mas felizmente o resultado dessa conta já está representada nos comentários do próprio objdump: é a posição de memória `2004`. A seção `.rodata` apresentada acima começa no endereço `2000`. Ao olharmos 4 bytes para direita, encontramos os bytes: `6f2c2077 6f726c64 2100`, ou `"Hello, world!"`.

Repare que esse endereço 2004 não é o endereço absoluto na memória do computador, mas sim o endereço relativo ao binário. Como os endereços são relativos, quando o sistema operacional carregar o executável na memória, ele continuará apontando para posição certa.

Já a linha `mov %rax,%rdi` move o registrador `rax` para o registrador `rdi`, que age como um ponteiro para uma posição de memória, e em seguida o comando `call 1050 <puts@plt>` chama a função que faz a impressão em si.